# There's a way for have different response on the FXML file objects using just one one method?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a program that allows user to book a seat and change color (in that case change just the image) when a place is selected. My code actually work fine, but I think is verbose and there should be a more efficient way, and also is not possible to "unselect" the seat.

There's a way for write just one methods that depending on which button (I used normal Images with onClick="#..." statement) changes the image on the particular image/button selected ?

In the Controller class I declared the object type:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class TheatreController {

  @FXML
  private ImageView a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3;

@FXML
  private void ona2Click(){
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Do you want to proceed with the booking?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    Image redSeat = new Image("sample/resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96.png");
    a2.setImage(redSeat);
  }

  @FXML
  private void ona3Click(){
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Do you want to proceed with the booking?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    Image redSeat = new Image("sample/resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96.png");
    a3.setImage(redSeat);
  }

  @FXML
  private void onb1Click(){
    ...
  }
```

---

```
FXML:
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="505.0" prefWidth="650.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4ce4ef;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.CharlotteBronteController">
    <children>
        <GridPane alignment="CENTER" layoutX="194.0" layoutY="146.0" prefHeight="214.0" prefWidth="262.0">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <ImageView fx:id="a1" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" onMouseClicked="#ona1Click">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fx:id="a2" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" onMouseClicked="#ona2Click">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fx:id="a3" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" onMouseClicked="#ona3Click">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fx:id="b1" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.rowIndex="1" onMouseClicked="#onb1Click">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fx:id="b2" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" onMouseClicked="#onb2Click">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fx:id="b3" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" onMouseClicked="#onb3Click">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fx:id="c1" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.rowIndex="2" onMouseClicked="#onc1Click">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fx:id="c2" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" onMouseClicked="#onc2Click">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fx:id="c3" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" onMouseClicked="#onc3Click">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
            </children>
        </GridPane>
      <Label layoutX="227.0" layoutY="122.0" text="A" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="316.0" layoutY="122.0" text="B" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="400.0" layoutY="122.0" text="C" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="168.0" layoutY="168.0" text="1" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="168.0" layoutY="244.0" text="2" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="168.0" layoutY="312.0" text="3" textFill="WHITE" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests to improve your working code should be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the node the event handler is registered for using the `getSource` method of the event object.

This allows you to use a single event handler method. Furthermore I recommend creating only one instance of `Image` for red and green seats respectively.

Making the `Label`s part of the `GridPane` and using a loop to fill the `GridPane` would make for code with much less repetition btw; personally I wouldn't use fxml to write this kind of view at all to avoid the repetition the similar `<ImageView>` elements ect.

```
@FXML
private Image redSeat;
@FXML
private Image greenSeat;

@FXML
private void onClick(MouseEvent event) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Do you want to proceed with the (un)booking?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    if (alert.showAndWait().orElse(ButtonType.NO) == ButtonType.YES) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) event.getSource();
        imageView.setImage(imageView.getImage() == redSeat ? greenSeat : redSeat);
    }
}
```

```xml
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="505.0" prefWidth="650.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4ce4ef;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.CharlotteBronteController">
    <fx:define>
        <Image fx:id="redSeat" url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96.png" />
    </fx:define>
    <children>
        <GridPane alignment="CENTER" layoutX="194.0" layoutY="146.0" prefHeight="214.0" prefWidth="262.0">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" onMouseClicked="#onClick">
                    <image>
                        <Image fx:id="greenSeat" url="@../resources/seatsandicons/icons8-armchair-96-3.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" onMouseClicked="#onClick">
                    <image>
                        <fx:reference source="greenSeat"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" onMouseClicked="#onClick">
                    <image>
                        <fx:reference source="greenSeat"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.rowIndex="1" onMouseClicked="#onClick">
                    <image>
                        <fx:reference source="greenSeat"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" onMouseClicked="#onClick">
                    <image>
                        <fx:reference source="greenSeat"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" onMouseClicked="#onClick">
                    <image>
                        <fx:reference source="greenSeat"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.rowIndex="2" onMouseClicked="#onClick">
                    <image>
                        <fx:reference source="greenSeat"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" onMouseClicked="#onClick">
                    <image>
                        <fx:reference source="greenSeat"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" onMouseClicked="#onClick">
                    <image>
                        <fx:reference source="greenSeat"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
            </children>
        </GridPane>
      <Label layoutX="227.0" layoutY="122.0" text="A" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="316.0" layoutY="122.0" text="B" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="400.0" layoutY="122.0" text="C" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="168.0" layoutY="168.0" text="1" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="168.0" layoutY="244.0" text="2" textFill="WHITE" />
      <Label layoutX="168.0" layoutY="312.0" text="3" textFill="WHITE" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```